# Overridden function applied to base class list

Tags: c++, inheritance, overloading, virtual

i just want to know if there is any way to do something like this:

```
Class A {}; //Base class

Class B : A {}; //B inherits from A

Class C : A {}; //C inherits from A

...
...
...

void func(B){do x;}
void func(C){do y;}
...
...
...
list<A> l //l contains Bs or Cs.

for each element in l {func(element);}
```

And get the expected behaviour for each one?

Comment: You have to make `A` have a `virtual` destructor, and the function you want to override be `virtual` also; and then use `list<A*>`, or preferably, `list< shared_ptr<A> >`

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like the following:

```
    class A // Base clss
    {
       public: // or protected, depends on your needs
         virtual void func() {};
    };

    class B : public A //B inherits from A
    {
       public: // or protected, depends on your needs
         void func() { do x };
    }; 

    class C : public A //C inherits from A
    {
       public: // or protected, depends on your needs
         void func() { do y };
    }; 

    ...
    ...
    ...

    list<A*> l //l contains Bs or Cs.

    for each element in l { element->func(); }
```

In this way you use polymorphism instead of overloading the static function func.

Comment: Does not work, objects get sliced when they are put into the `list<A>`.

Comment: Yes, you're right, of course it has to be list<A*>. My code snippet was more of a pseudo-code to explain the classes structure. Also "do x" and "do y" do not work then...

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class A
{
public:
    virtual void func() {}
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    void func()
    {
        std::cout << "B prints x" << std::endl;
    }
};

class C : public A
{
public:
    void func()
    {
        std::cout << "C prints y" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<A*> v;
    v.push_back(new B());
    v.push_back(new C());
    for (std::vector<A*>::iterator it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it){
        (*it)->func();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
B prints x
C prints y
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use polymorphism. For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>

class A 
{
public:
   virtual ~A() {}
   virtual void do_it() = 0;  
};

class B : public A 
{
public:
   virtual void do_it() { std::cout << "processing of B\n"; };  

};

class C : public A 
{
public:
   virtual void do_it() { std::cout << "processing of C\n"; };  
};

void f( std::unique_ptr<A> &pa ) { pa->do_it(); }

int main()
{
    std::list<std::unique_ptr<A>> l;
    l.push_back( std::unique_ptr<A>( new B ) );
    l.push_back( std::unique_ptr<A>( new C ) );

    std::for_each( l.begin(), l.end(), f );
}
```